# C# app not saving to xml

Tags: c#, xml, save, loading

I have been working with xml for the first time and have gotten stuck with the saving/ loading aspect of it. I want the information from the text boxes to be saved to the xml file when the app closes, however when the app runs I can not close the app with the "X' in the top right corner. I have tried deleting the xml file and recreating it, but that still doesnt help.

I got the app to close now and the saving function does work with the xml. However the load function is not going through it's foreach loop to add the information from the xml back into the app

```
 XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(path + place);
            foreach( XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("ClientMeasurements\\Client"))
            {
                Client c = new Client();

                c.Name = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
                c.InitialForearm = xNode.SelectSingleNode("InitialForearm").InnerText;
                c.InitialUpperArmR = xNode.SelectSingleNode("InitialUpperArmRight").InnerText;
                c.InitialUpperArmL = xNode.SelectSingleNode("InitialUpperArmLeft").InnerText;
                c.InitialChest = xNode.SelectSingleNode("InitialChest").InnerText;
                c.InitialWaist = xNode.SelectSingleNode("InitialWaist").InnerText;
                c.InitialHips = xNode.SelectSingleNode("InitialHips").InnerText;
                c.InitialThighR = xNode.SelectSingleNode("InitialThighRight").InnerText;
                c.InitialThighL = xNode.SelectSingleNode("InitialThighLeft").InnerText;
                c.InitialCalfR = xNode.SelectSingleNode("InitialCalfRight").InnerText;
                c.InitialCalfL = xNode.SelectSingleNode("InitialCalfLeft").InnerText;
                c.MostRecentForearm = xNode.SelectSingleNode("MostRecentForearm").InnerText;
                c.MostRecentUpperArmR = xNode.SelectSingleNode("MostRecentUpperArmRight").InnerText;
                c.MostRecentUpperArmL = xNode.SelectSingleNode("MostRecentUpperArmLeft").InnerText;
                c.MostRecentChest = xNode.SelectSingleNode("MostRecentChest").InnerText;
                c.MostRecentWaist = xNode.SelectSingleNode("MostRecentWaist").InnerText;
                c.MostRecentHips = xNode.SelectSingleNode("MostRecentHips").InnerText;
                c.MostRecentThighR = xNode.SelectSingleNode("MostRecentThighRight").InnerText;
                c.MostRecentThighL = xNode.SelectSingleNode("MostRecentThighLeft").InnerText;
                c.MostRecentCalfR = xNode.SelectSingleNode("MostRecentCalfRight").InnerText;
                c.MostRecentCalfL = xNode.SelectSingleNode("MostRecentCalfLeft").InnerText;

                client.Add(c);
                listView1.Items.Add(c.Name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't click the close button? Is it grayed out? Does it hang when you click it?

Comment: the App is unresponsive when i click it. Its not greyed out, the button clicks, but doesn't close the app out.

Comment: have you tried to put a breakpoint and see which line of code or method call is troubling?

Comment: No because the app runs fine, but wont close and save to the xml file. I thought breakpoints were only for where the code causes a crash

Comment: Debug your code - put breakpoint and step through to see what is going on... If it does not help - make **small** sample that reproduces the problem (check out http://www.sscce.org) - right now you have a lot of nearly identical lines of code that do not add any new information about the problem. Side note: node names with spaces is an unusual practice for XML and causes error while creating the node, I assume you node names are just samples not real ones.

Comment: I got the app to close now, but it still doesnt save to the xml file. The reason the app wouldnt close was because the xml format was wrong like you said

Comment: I also got the foreach loop to work, but it only goes through the loop once and stops before it completes "client.Add(c);" and "listView1.Items.Add(c.Name);

Comment: Thanks everyone I got the bug fixed there was a problem with the xml format and after that was fixed the whole problem I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way to do this using XML serialization.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part-1) is a article to get you started.

Basically you want to decorate your Client class with `[Serializeable]` and then use something like this to save and load your `clients` object (which I'm assuming is some kind of collection) from an XML file:

```
    public static void SerializeObject<T>(T serializableObject, string fileName)
    {
        if (serializableObject == null) { return; }

        try
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObject);
                stream.Position = 0;
                xmlDocument.Load(stream);
                xmlDocument.Save(fileName);
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            //Log exception here
        }
    }

    public static T DeSerializeObject<T>(string fileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) { return default(T); }

        T objectOut = default(T);

        try
        {
            string attributeXml = string.Empty;

            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.Load(fileName);
            string xmlString = xmlDocument.OuterXml;

            using (StringReader read = new StringReader(xmlString))
            {
                Type outType = typeof(T);

                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(outType);
                using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(read))
                {
                    objectOut = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    reader.Close();
                }

                read.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log exception here
        }

        return objectOut;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I would like to know what is wrong with the way the code is now thats preventing it from saving/loading for a future reference